# How to setup etckeeper with Mercurial in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, etckeeper

I'm interested in installing etckeeper with Mercurial in my Ubuntu system. My reason is that I don't know how to use Git and don't want to learn at the moment. If I check the package description it sounds promising:

```
kent@rat:~$ apt-cache search etckeeper
etckeeper - store /etc in git, mercurial, or bzr
```

I'm wondering how to continue on from here? I've tried Googling but I haven't found anything for the Ubuntu + etckeeper + Mercurial combination.

(If you know of a good tutorial for this situation, a link is an excellent answer. No need to re-iterate.)

Comment: +1 Thank you for unintentionally advising an interesting tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using etckeeper on both debian and ubuntu. It's painless.

Just do a `sudo etckeeper init` and you're done!

Actually, you may need to edit `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` to check that `hg` is selected as your VCS command. But that's all that you need to do.

Once that is done etckeeper will begin tracking every change that you make to files in `/etc` and commit those changes to the local repository. This happens automatically whenever you run `apt-get` on anything and also as a nightly cron-job.

However, if you wish to push your changes to a remote repository, you will need to do it manually or setup something else to do it for you.

Comment: Ah. Good to know! Now I feel ready to try it.

Comment: Worth noting (for rookies) that "sudo apt-get install mercurial" will be needed if it's not already installed, followed by appropriate configuration (probably of ~/.hgrc) as described in the output of "hg help config".

Comment: I don't think hg needs much configuration for use with etckeeper - all I did was install hgk (for "hg view"), on Ubuntu 8.04.  For more recent Ubuntus, just apt-get install hgview for the (improved) "hgview".  Both provide a GUI to browse or search commits to the repository, which is handy for those who aren't skilled in use of Mercurial (hg).

Answer (score 8):

On my system (Ubuntu Karmic), besides setting `VCS="hg"`, I had to edit `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` and add the following or else `etckeeper commit` would complain about a missing username:

```
HG_COMMIT_OPTIONS="-u etckeeper@aeolus"
```

Also, in `/etc/.hg/hgrc`, I added the following:

```
[ui]
username = root@aeolus
```

That way, when I do a commit through etckeeper, the username on that commit will be `etckeeper@aeolus`, and if I do a commit manually via mercurial, it will show up as `root@aeolus`.

Comment: I just set up a new system with the advice from @sybreon, and had the same "missing username" error.  Your second step, adding the username to the [ui] section of (in my case) ~/.hgrc, was sufficient to get past the problem.  I don't think the HG_COMMIT_OPTIONS part is required.

Comment: No, it isn't. I just added that so that automatic and manual commits would show up with different user names. That way I know which commits in the log were done manually by me, after making some change.